# how to run composer install?

Tags: composer-php, failed-installation, symfony3.x

I'm trying to install composer using "composer install" but i get this error. I've searched about it but there is no solution for me.
I just understood that it's a version compatibility problem

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.41
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.40
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.39
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.38
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.35
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.34
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.33
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.32
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.31
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.30
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.28
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.27
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.26
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.25
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.24
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.23
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.22
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.3
    - Installation request for vich/uploader-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by vich/uploader-bundle[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.1
```

I've tried to fix symfony/form by adding it manuali in my composer.json file but still not work!

```
    - vich/uploader-bundle dev-master requires symfony/form ^4.4 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/form[v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9, v5.1.0].
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v4.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.0.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - don't install symfony/form v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony ^3.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.4, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9].
```

and here is my "composer.json"

```
    "name": "lukas/directory-platform",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        },
        "files": [
            "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "adamquaile/symfony-fieldset-bundle": "^1.1",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.6",
        "payum/offline": "^1.4",
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.4",
        "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.2",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "^3.3",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
        "twig/twig": "^2.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    }
}
```

how can i fix this error please and thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the given message, `vich/uploader-bundle` using the version constraint `dev-master` requires Symfony 4.4 or 5. This is not compatible with your version constraint `^3.3` for `symfony/symfony`.

After all, is there any need to use the latest untagged version of `vich/uploader-bundle`? Keep in mind that this might contain stuff that is broken and should not be used in production, in constrast to tagged versions.

Using the version constraint `^1.11` for that bundle, you should be able to install it properly.